# how to retrieve in app message custom payload data in android?

Tags: firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

However, I see an option to set custom data in the console under the following path:

In-App Messaging -> Compose Campaign -> Additional Options

So I have set the key-value pairs as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you try on the real campaign?

Maybe it is a bug on iOS, but when you test in-app message via "Test on device" button fields like `inAppMessage.campaignInfo.campaignName`, `inAppMessage.appData` are empty.

On the real campaign, it works fine.